# Trying to understand the mechanics of a synchronous queue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, nonblocking, java.util.concurrent

I was trying to read the implementation of [Synchronous Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html)
It is not so straightforward for me. It seems to be using a linked list where each node is associated with a thread.
And the core part uses a spin loop waiting for tasks to be placed in the queue.
I was wondering why is a spin loop being used instead of something like `wait/notify`?
Now this way one of the cores is gone due to this constant spin loop, right?
I am trying to understand this point and get a rough understanding of the design of the Synchronous Queue

**UPDATE**
What is also troubling me is how the waiter threads start/stop.

Comment: That is the basis of lock-free algorithms - note that the spinning is only done when there is something to transfer. As soon as the transfer is done or if there is nothing to do, the method returns.

Comment: @assylias:In most parts of `TransferQueue.transferer` there is a `continue` not a `return`.There is a return in a few cases in which case I have no idea what happens to the waiters and when/how they restart

Answer (score 4):

The point of the `SynchronousQueue` is to synchronize something which is usually quite asynchronous - one thread placing an item into the queue while another tries to take from it.

The `SynchronousQueue` is actually not a queue at all. It has no capacity, no internal storage. It only allows taking from the queue when another process is currently trying to put in the queue.

Example:

Process A tries to put in the queue. This blocks for now.
Process B tries to take from the queue. Since someone is trying to put, the item is transferred from A to B, and both are unblocked.

Process B tries to take from the queue, but no one tries to put. So B is now blocked.
Process A now wants to put an item. Now the item is transferred over to B, and A and B are no longer blocked.

About the blocking:

The Sun/Oracle JRE implementation does use polling instead of a wait/notify pattern if you do a timed operation (like "try to take for 1 second"). This makes sense: it periodically retries until the time is up. When you do a non-timed operation (like "take, no matter how long it takes" it does use `park`, which wakes again if the situation has changed. In neither situation would one of your cores be constantly busy spinning a loop. The `for (;;)` means "retry indefinately" in this case, it does not mean "constant spinning".

Comment: I think that there is no actual blocking.I mean the blocking part is implemented via a spin loop.This loop "eats" cpu cycles.Why wasn't the blocking implemented via some form of `wait` or `sleep`?

Comment: You think wrong, then ;-) There is blocking. Which is why the API doc you linked opens with the sentence `"A blocking queue in which each insert operation must wait for a corresponding remove operation by another thread, and vice versa."`

Comment: But you are quoting the javadoc.I already mentioned that I tried to understand the implementation where I found `for (;;) {` in the implementation of `transfer`.

Comment: Having found the code you were talking about, I edited my answer. Please tell me if this is what you were asking about.

Comment: `for (;;) means "retry indefinately" in this case` So when does this end?

Comment: When `break` or `return` are exexuted.

Comment: Don't seem to happen to me. Or if they do, how the waiters restart